# How to read stratigraphy data?

Tags: geology

I have a list of geological data.
The data is for 3 variables: member, level and L+/-

These variables correspond to a particular position on a stratigraphic column/chart.

I would like help with precisely knowing which level -3 refers to?  Is it the level 3 units from the bottom of the column upwards, or from the top of the column downwards?  Thank you.

Comment: Without seeing the chart or having more information this is difficult to answer, standardization took a while with stratigraphic sections.